# Create table with fields of one column as columns

Tags: sql

I have this table:

Primary Table

[image]

`select name, specialty_source, specialty_1__v, specialty_2__v
from   sk_initial`

And I want to query the table to have that result:

Final Table

[image]

As you can see in the first table I have the specialties in the source in different rows where all of the rest is equal but I want to create the column speciality_1_SRC with the result of the first row and speciality_2_SRC with the result of the second row and everything remains equal. Can you help me with that?

**You can have 3 specialties maximum**

Comment: Please, no images (or links to them), use formatted text instead.

Comment: Please add the relevant code as text to your question also table should be in text format instead of Screenshot.Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Will the maximum number of specialties for a person be fixed? Or may Maria specialize in D later?

Comment: Please add at the least SQL create statements, better yet an sql fiddle

Comment: What defines the "first" row?

Comment: @jarlh One person can have only 3 Specialties in the Source, is the maximum

Comment: @jarlh I am using Amazon Web Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do it without using stored proc you can, first, get the min_max, then, join the result set to that table for the purpose of getting the mid. The only disadvantage of this is, if there are records that have only two Specialty_source the mid will be null.

```
WITH min_max AS (
select a.name,
       min(a.specialty_source) as spec_1_source,
        COALESCE(nullif(max(a.specialty_source), min(a.specialty_source)),'') as spec_3_source,
       a.specialty_1, a.specialty_2
from yourtable a 
group by a.name, a.specialty_1, a.specialty_2
)
SELECT min_max.name,
  min_max.spec_1_source,
  mid.specialty_source spec_2_source,
  min_max.spec_3_source,
  min_max.specialty_1,
  min_max.specialty_2
FROM yourtable mid RIGHT OUTER JOIN min_max ON (mid.name=min_max.name AND mid.specialty_source NOT IN (min_max.spec_1_source,min_max.spec_3_source) )
```

[SEE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=10d8b80547ff57076393181037db8c1f)

Answer (score 0):

This answers the ORIGINAL question which only had two specialty columns.

I think aggregation does what you want:

```
select name,
       min(spec_source) as spec_1_source,
       nullif(max(spec_source), min(spec_source)) as spec_2_source,
       spec_1, spec_2
from t
group by name, spec_1, spec_2;
```

Comment: But we can have 3 specialties

Comment: @martaferreira . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask it as a NEW question.  Be sure to have a proper explanation.